# Equivalent of WITH (NOLOCK) in AWS Athena

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, amazon-quicksight

I tried to use "WITH (NOLOCK)" in a SQL query in AWS Athena, and it doesn't seem to recognize the "NOLOCK". It throws an error on the NOLOCK specifically. Is there some kind of equivalent that should be used instead?

Thanks so much for the help!

Here is my query:
`SELECT * FROM "usage_dw_large"."usage_sites" WITH (NOLOCK) limit 10;`

Here is the error:
`line 1:46: mismatched input 'with'. expecting: ',', '.', 'as', 'cross', 'except', 'for', 'full', 'group', 'having', 'inner', 'intersect', 'join', 'left', 'limit', 'natural', 'order', 'right', 'tablesample', 'union', 'where', <eof>, <identifier> (service: amazonathena; status code: 400; error code: invalidrequestexception; request id: 9aec79f3-9073-4adb-bff8-203fb617eb3e; proxy: null)`

Comment: Databases don't really like returning inaccurate data, so I wouldn't expect `NOLOCK` -- which allows inconsistent data to be returned -- to be available in other databases.

Comment: I would start by explaining why you do you think you need the "nolock" in the first place.

Comment: What exactly does `WITH (NOLOCK)` do?

Comment: @JorgeCampos If I understand correctly, WITH (NOLOCK) prevents a database from locking while being read. This allows multiple processes to read and write to the database simultaneously. The assumption is that data is being written in a way and with a frequency in which concurrent reads don't produce enough inaccurate data to cause a problem. (I'm only reading data.) Also, if there are a lot of processes that read large amounts of data simultaneously then queries needing exclusive access to the database causes a backup.

The real reason though is that a senior engineer told me to use it. 

Comment: I honestly think that your senior engineer doesn't understand how Athena works then. Athena is not really a database it is a way for one to read data from S3 files, at least that's what I used it for. So it is understandable it won't support no lock

Comment: May be your senior engineer is referring to S3 eventual consistency issue. AWS now offers S3 Strong consistency. Refer this link: https://aws.amazon.com/s3/consistency/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no equivalent.  AWS Athena was built on [PrestoDB](https://prestodb.io/) and here is an except from [PrestoDB's docs](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/overview/use-cases.html):

> Do not mistake the fact that Presto understands SQL with it providing the features of a standard database. Presto is not a general-purpose relational database. It is not a replacement for databases like MySQL, PostgreSQL or Oracle. Presto was not designed to handle Online Transaction Processing (OLTP). This is also true for many other databases designed and optimized for data warehousing or analytics.

There are no row/table locks like traditional relational databases so this keyword/feature is not included or needed.